# ElastAlert Spike Alert for Multiple API's

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastalert

I am new to elastic alerts and trying to write an alert where there will be a field in the index with the name api which refers to API name ( String ). Now I want to create a spike alert such that for each name in API if the spike is generated, it should send me a unique message with the API name and the current count of requests to slack. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you running the ES on own machine or using ES from Cloud provider(AWS or someone)?

Comment: On Some Cloud Server. But is it relevant

Comment: I am familiar with AWS ES, they actual create metrics and you can have cloud watch alarm or SNS to inform you based on the metrics threshold.